# retrieve name from the other table

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Is there an efficient way of retrieving the name by using select and join clause? I have a Note, NoteType and NoteStatus model. There are type and status field which will be stored as integer (representing the id of its respective model) inside Note model. NoteType and NoteStatus models have id and name fields.

```
foreach($notes as $note)
{
    $type=NoteType::where('id',$note->type)->first();
    $note->type=$type->name;
    $status=NoteStatus::where('id',$note->status)->first();
    $note->status=$status->name;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the relationships set in up between these models?

Comment: @RossWilson no relationship between these models, that's why thinking of using query builder

Answer (score 1):

### Model Relations

Setting up relations between your models would be the best way as you then don't need to re-invent the wheel each time you need to call the join. It will save you code in the long run.

More info on this here:

[Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

### Query Builder

If you want to do this manually then it would be the same as if you ran the query in raw SQL:

```
$note = Note::join('NoteType','Note.NoteType_id','NoteType.id')
->select('Note.*','NoteType.Name as NoteName')
->first();
```

Now you can get all the info from $note

```
Note id = $note->id
NoteType Name = $note->NoteName
```

Obviously adjust this to your code but this should help you build your knowledge enough to work it out.

More info can be found here:

[Laravel Query Builder Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that Your model name is `Note.php`

assume in your `notes` table has `note_status_id` and `note_type_id` foreign key

Add Relationship in your main model `Note.php`

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(NoteStatus::class);
}

public function notes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(NoteType::class);
}
```

You can retrieve data with relationship something like that

```
Note::with('status','notes')
     ->get()
```

For more info regarding laravel relationship [Laravel Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)